# How to fix "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect/CGSize' is ambiguous without more context"?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I have an existing codebase that was written in Swift 3 and Xcode 9 that I am having trouble migrating to Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2 due to build errors within the code.

The problem I am running into now is this:

*"Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context"*

I am getting this error in 3 different areas of my code. The fourth one is related but different in that it says:

*"Expression type '(CGSize) -> CGSize' is ambiguous without more context"*

I have tried changing all values within the expression to explicitly use the data type CGFloat to remove any inferred data type errors, and this still did not fix the problem.

```
 override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let adjustedHeight = 8.0 + titleLabel.frame.height + 2.0 + underlineView.frame.height
    adjustedHeight += 16.0 + mapImageView.frame.height + 16.0
    return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: adjustedHeight)
}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let adjustedHeight = 10.0 + titleLabel.frame.height + 15.0 + daysRoundedView.frame.height
    adjustedHeight += daysTextLabel.frame.height + 10.0 + logoImageView.frame.height + 20.0
    return CGSize(width: size.width, height: adjustedHeight)
}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let adjustedHeight = 8.0 + titleLabel.frame.height + 2.0
    adjustedHeight += underlineView.frame.height + 16.0 + flyerImageView.frame.height + 16.0
    return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: adjustedHeight)
}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let adjustedHeight = 8.0 + titleLabel.frame.height + 2.0 +  underlineView.frame.height + 16.0
    adjustedHeight += descriptionTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width - 40, height: size.height)).height + 16.0
    return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: adjustedHeight)
}
```

The issue is with the adjustedHeight variable. I'm not sure if a different function or syntax is used in Swift 4.2 for this but I cannot seem to fix this error.

Comment: Change `let` to `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the issues is that `adjustedHeight` is a let, but it's being modified in the next line with the `+=` operator. Does the issue get fixed after you change `adjustedHeight` to var?